# Calling OnPropertyChanged when a property of a property changes

Tags: c#, mvvm, windows-runtime

I have a property `MyProperty` in my viewmodel which also has some properties. I want to call `OnPropertyChanged("MyProperty")` explicitly only when one of its properties change.

I can do this

```
MyProperty.PropertyChanged += MyPropertyChanged;
```

but then the handler is called when all of the properties change. I know I can check if the `PropertyName` matches but I would like to know if there is a better way.

The reason I need this is because I am binding `MyProperty` to some controls and in a converter I need to use more than one of its properties, but when these properties change the change is not visible in the control.

Comment: Why not raise the `PropertyChanged` sequentially for both properties?

Comment: I am not sure I can do it. I'm talking here about MyProperty and one of its properties (MyPropertyProperty). The solution would be to call OnPropertyChanged("MyProperty") in my viewmodel when MyPropertyProperty changes, but I dont know how to achieve this

Comment: Oh then you have to do the way you mentioned above checking the property name in handler and raising it by yourself. Why you think that it's not better solution?

Comment: That's a holly grail of binding - there're not major improvements. One thing you could do, and I've seen that. `Make a PropertyTracker class, like a 'bag class'`. Add all properties that need tracking there (as `INotifyPropertyChanged` objects) - and internally do some `generic processing` for them all. Raise a `OnPropertyChanged` for property that changes. Once you do that, you can just reuse. The only smarter thing I've seen, other than manually doing it. You'd need to do some leg work there, maybe use lambda etc.

Comment: Ok, I will stick with checking PropertyName method, but thanks

Comment: I had a similar problem and thought I'd add a comment here in case anyone else runs into it.  I had a command in view/viewmodel that was part of a shared library; the last thing the command needed to do was restart the application, which was problematic, as I didn't want the library to know anything about the specific applications.  Using Filip's suggestion, I created another null command in my viewmodel that the original command called, and then I assigned it within the final app.  Bam, everything was wonderful, and I get to go home early the day before Thanksgiving.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If properties of the type of your MyProperty are never bound to anything then there's no reason for that type to implement INotifyPropertyChanged. Regardless of whether it does or not - if you need any manual handling of changes to one of its properties you can simply define a custom event that you raise when it changes and handle in your view model. If you are already using PropertyChanged and comparing strings - you should be fine unless the event occurs many times per second,